# How to execute a .app program(file) at pre-build of build.gradle in Android

Tags: android, macos, gradle, groovy

I am building an Android application that runs a program before the prebuild.

In build.gradle file, I have a:

```
task runFile(type:Exec) {
    workingDir './path/to/.app/'

    commandLine 'sh', 'app_file.app'
preBuild.dependsOn runFile
```

When I run, I get an error saying:

```
app_file.app: app_file.app: is a directory
```

and can't run it.

Is there any way I could run the application using this file on mac?

I got this working on windows with .exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `app_file.app` on OS X just looks like an executable file to you. In reality it indeed is just a directory with some standard file structure as the error suggested. To start an `.app` from terminal or in this case Gradle, you should use the `open` utility. So use `open` instead of `sh` and it should work fine.